# Cakephp 3.x Table "Admin\Model\Table\ImagesTable" is not associated with "Url"

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to record in the image table file.

```
namespace Admin\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class ImagesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->table('images');
    $this->hasMany('ImageAlbums', [
        'className' => 'Admin.ImageAlbums',
        'foreignKey' => 'conver_image_id'
    ]);
    }

  public function saveImage($imageDescription, $imageName, $albumId){
    $imageEntity = $this->newEntity();
    $imageData = [  'imageDescription' => $imageDescription,
                    'imageOriginalUrl' => $this->Url->build('/', true).'original-img/'.$imageName,
                    'imageSmallUrl' => $this->Url->build('/', true).'small-img/'.$imageName,
                    'imageMediumUrl' => $this->Url->build('/', true).'medium-img/'.$imageName,
                    'imageBigUrl' => $this->Url->build('/', true).'big-img/'.$imageName,
                    'album_id' => $albumId];
    $imageEntity = $this->patchEntity($imageEntity, $imageData);
    return $this->save($imageEntity);
  }
}
```

I call this method('saveImage') in the image albums controller.

```
$image = $this->ImageAlbums->Images->saveImage("description.", 'natural.jpg', $this->enumArray['albums']['albumConverImages']);
```

Associating the picture albums chart this code.

```
$this->belongsTo('Images', [
            'className' => 'Admin.Images',
            'foreignKey' => 'conver_image_id'
        ]);
```

I get this error. 'Table "Admin\Model\Table\ImagesTable" is not associated with "Url"'

I want to create image album. I would like to add a picture of the album cover. Can you help me? Can you suggest a way the error solutions or a different solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `$this->Url->build(...)` inside of a table class function, but Url is a helper, which isn't available to tables. Try using `Router::url(...)` instead. The Url build method is just a wrapper for that anyway!

Comment: Thanks bro.  use Cake\Routing\Router; Router::url('/',true); Code is success.